# convert dataframe to nested dictionary (one nesting level per column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this dataframe:

```
COL0    COL1    COL2    COL3
----------------------------
   A      A1     A11    A111
   A      A1     A11    A112
   A      A1     A12    A113
   A      A1     A12    A114
   A      A2     A13    A115
   A      A2     A13    A116
   A      A2     A14    A117
   A      A2     A14    A118
```

And I would like to obtain a dictionary like the below from it. If I just apply the to_dict() method to the original dataframe, the format is not what I would like.

```
{
    'A':{
        'A1':{
            'A11':['A111', 'A112'],
            'A12':['A113', 'A114']
        },
        'A2':{
            'A13':['A115', 'A116'],
            'A13':['A117', 'A118']            
        }
    }
}
```

PS: snippet to generate the above dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'COL0': ['A']*8,
    'COL1': ['A1']*4 + ['A2']*4,
    'COL2': ['A11']*2 + ['A12']*2 + ['A12']*2 + ['A13']*2,
    'COL3': [f'A11{i+1}' for i in range(8)]
})
```

EDIT:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 {a: {k: f.groupby('COL2')['COL3'].apply(list).to_dict()
> 2            for k, f in g.groupby('COL1')}
> ----> 3        for a, g in df.groupby('COL0')}
>
> in (.0)
> 1 {a: {k: f.groupby('COL2')['COL3'].apply(list).to_dict()
> 2            for k, f in g.groupby('COL1')}
> ----> 3        for a, g in df.groupby('COL0')}
>
> in (.0)
> 1 {a: {k: f.groupby('COL2')['COL3'].apply(list).to_dict()
> ----> 2            for k, f in g.groupby('COL1')}
> 3        for a, g in df.groupby('COL0')}
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py
> in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
> 219     )
> 220     def apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
> --> 221         return super().apply(func, *args, **kwargs)
> 222
> 223     @doc(_agg_template, examples=_agg_examples_doc, klass="Series")
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py
> in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
> 865     def apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
> 866
> --> 867         func = self._is_builtin_func(func)
> 868
> 869         # this is needed so we don't try and wrap strings. If we could
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py
> in _is_builtin_func(self, arg)
> 342         otherwise return the arg
> 343         """
> --> 344         return self._builtin_table.get(arg, arg)
> 345
> 346
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

EDIT2:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 out = {}
> ----> 2 for keys, v in df.groupby(list(df.columns[:-1]))[df.columns[-1]]:
> 3     d = out             # restart at root
> 4     val = v.to_list()
> 5     for k in keys:
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the rows and collect key-value pairs; use `dict.setdefault` to set a default value if a key doesn't exist yet:

```
out = {}
for w,x,y,z in df.to_numpy():
    out.setdefault(w, {}).setdefault(x, {}).setdefault(y, []).append(z)
```

With `pd.groupby` and a nested dict comprehension:

```
out = {a: {k: f.groupby('COL2')['COL3'].apply(list).to_dict()
           for k, f in g.groupby('COL1')} 
       for a, g in df.groupby('COL0')}
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'A1': {'A11': ['A111', 'A112'], 'A12': ['A113', 'A114']},
  'A2': {'A13': ['A115', 'A116'], 'A14': ['A117', 'A118']}}}
```

Comment: Is there a way with pandas.groupby?

Comment: It throws: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @JaviTorre is the setdefault solution working?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that works with an arbitrary number of columns.

It uses first `groupby` to set the groups per all but the last column.

Then it goes down the tree, changing the reference to the parent until it reaches the last key.

```
out = {}
for keys, v in df.groupby(list(df.columns[:-1]))[df.columns[-1]]:
    d = out             # restart at root
    val = v.to_list()
    for k in keys:
        if k not in d:
            d[k] = {}   # create child if missing
        parent = d
        d = d[k]        # go down in nested level
    parent[k] = val     # we reached the bottom, set the value
```

output:

```
{'A': {'A1': {'A11': ['A111', 'A112'],
              'A12': ['A113', 'A114']},
       'A2': {'A13': ['A115', 'A116'],
              'A14': ['A117', 'A118']},
       },
}
```

Example on further nested dictionary:

```
from  itertools import product
df = (pd.DataFrame(product('AB', '12', '123', '1', '12'))
        .add_prefix('COL').cumsum(1)
      )
#    COL0 COL1 COL2  COL3   COL4
#  0    A   A1  A11  A111  A1111
#  1    A   A1  A11  A111  A1112
#  2    A   A1  A12  A121  A1211
#  3    A   A1  A12  A121  A1212
#  4    A   A1  A13  A131  A1311
# ...
# 23    B   B2  B23  B231  B2312
```

output:

```
{'A': {'A1': {'A11': {'A111': ['A1111', 'A1112']},
              'A12': {'A121': ['A1211', 'A1212']},
              'A13': {'A131': ['A1311', 'A1312']}},
       'A2': {'A21': {'A211': ['A2111', 'A2112']},
              'A22': {'A221': ['A2211', 'A2212']},
              'A23': {'A231': ['A2311', 'A2312']}}},
 'B': {'B1': {'B11': {'B111': ['B1111', 'B1112']},
              'B12': {'B121': ['B1211', 'B1212']},
              'B13': {'B131': ['B1311', 'B1312']}},
       'B2': {'B21': {'B211': ['B2111', 'B2112']},
              'B22': {'B221': ['B2211', 'B2212']},
              'B23': {'B231': ['B2311', 'B2312']}}}}
```

Comment: It throws TypeError: 'list' object is not callable what python version are you using?

Comment: python 3 ; can you provide the full error traceback?

Comment: please see it in my edit.

Comment: @Javi this is not my code, please try mine ;)

Comment: Apologies, see edit2